# strip для random.sample?

Tags: python

```
import random

test_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

print(random.sample(test_list, 1))
```

Печатает

```
['4']
```

Как убрать скобки и кавычки?
Так не получается:

```
import random

test_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

print(random.sample(test_list, 1)).strip()
```

Пишет:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Скобки и кавычки означают, что это а) список, б) в нем строка. Кавычки, кстати, у тебя самого в исходных данных есть. Как и убрать, и нужно ли вообще убирать, зависит от того, зачем ты хочешь их убрать. А судя по тому, что ты пытаешься убрать скобки и кавычки функцией strip(), ни документацию, ни учебники ты не читаешь. А зря!

Comment: print(random.sample(test_list, 1)[0])

Comment: В последнем примере кода должна выдаваться ошибка `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`, т. к. `print` возвращает `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно выбрать из списка ровно одно значение, то просто используйте `random.choice` вместо `random.sample`:

```
import random

test_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

print(random.choice(test_list))
```

`random.sample` используйте если нужно выбрать несколько значений из исходного набора. Эта функция возвращает список, в данном случае список строк. Чтобы объединить список строк в одну строку (вывести, например, `123` вместо `["1", "2", "3"]`), используйте метод `join`:

```
import random

test_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

print("".join(random.sample(test_list, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант ещё можно поставить `*`, тогда список "распакуется", а кавычки `print` не станет печатать у просто строки, не находящейся внутри списка:

```py
print(*random.sample(test_list, 1))
```